# Strcpy() copying pointer?

Tags: c, strcpy

I have a question about strcpy(). To my understanding, I thought that strcpy copies the bytes located at the pointers and not the pointers itself.
But this snippet of code seems to react differently.

```
char* str2  = (char*) malloc(50) ;
printf("str2:%d (%p), strTrim:%d (%p)", strlen(str2),*str2,strlen(strTrim),*strTrim) ;
strcpy(str2,strTrim);
printf("str2:%d (%p), strTrim:%d (%p)", strlen(str2),*str2,strlen(strTrim),*strTrim) ;
```

The output I get is:

```
str2: 64 (FFFFFFCD) , strTrim:8 (00000061)
str2:8 (00000061) , strTrim:8 (00000061)
```

Now, the first output line seems pretty clear to me. But the second line is confusing me. 
Why does it copy the pointer of strTrim to str2 ? I really don't get it.

Comment: If you are printing the value of the pointer, you should only supply `str2` and `strTrim` to the `printf` instead of `*str2` and `*strTrim` (which will actually print out the part of the memory that stores the string).

Answer (score 4):

```
char* str2  = (char*) malloc(50) ;
strlen(str2);  // undefined behavior, `str2` has an indeterminate value
```

After `malloc` the allocated object has an indeterminate value. You cannot call `strlen` with `str2` argument: it is not yet a string.

Nullify the first byte and `str2` will become a pointer to an (empty) string:

```
str2[0] = '\0';
strlen(str2); // OK, strlen(str2) is 0
```

Comment: Yes thanks, that's true. I should have removed that line of code. But it still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @MarianoDiMartino `*strTrim` and `*str2` are equivalent to `strTrim[0]` and `str2[0]` which is the first character of the strings. After a call to `strcpy` you get the same value for `strTrim[0]` and `str2[0]`.

Comment: To print the pointers value you need `printf("%p %p\n", strTrim, str2);` and not `*strTrim` and `*str2`.